# Not getting any return value from function [React Native]

Tags: function, react-native, return-value

I have this menu where I filter the button when user is logged and I'm accessing a function from a separate file to check out if user is logged or not.

**From menu**

```
import { IsLogged } from '../GlobalFunctions';

const SubDrawer1 = ({ data, onChange }) => (
    <View>
    {
        IsLogged() ? (
            <View>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{onChange('LogoutScreen')}}>
                    <Text>Logout</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        ) : (<View />)
    }     
    </View>
);
export default SubDrawer1;
```

**From GlobalFunctions**

```
export function IsLogged(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then((userId) => {
        return userId ? true : false
    })
}
```

From *menu* I call out `IsLogged()` function but the value is `undefined` when I console.log it. It supposed to return either `true` or `false`.

Comment: If you don't have key which is 'userId', AsyncStorage return undefined.
It is natural.
Check whether AsyncStorage have 'userId' as key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call a async function, so you need to add some extra code. Try the following.

> SubDrawer1

```
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";

import React, { Component } from "react";
import { IsLogged } from "../GlobalFunctions";

const SubDrawer1 = async ({ data, onChange }) => {
  const status = await IsLogged();
  if (status === true) {
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => {
              onChange("LogoutScreen");
            }}
          >
            <Text>Logout</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View>
        <View />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default SubDrawer1;
```

> 'IsLogged()' Global function

```
export function async IsLogged(){
    let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
    return userId ? true : false
}
```

> 'SubDrawer1' using class

```
...

import SubDrawer1 from "./SubDrawer1"; // import your 'SubDrawer1' component

var subDrawer1Component; // declare a variable for your rendering component

//Your main class
export default class ClassName extends Component<Props> {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getComponentInfo(); //Call this method to get function
  }

  getComponentInfo = async () => {
    subDrawer1Component = await SubDrawer1();// Will take the component
    this.setState({ isDataGet: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
        ...

        {subDrawer1Component}

        ...
    );
  }

}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

because AsyncStorage will take some time, and before that function completes its execution. (Because everything in JS is asynchronous)

So just make it wait until it finishes getting an item,

```
export function async IsLogged(){
    let userId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userId');
    return userId ? true : false
}
```

Comment: I tried applying this and there is an error appearing on the line `export function async IsLogged()` when I add `async`

Comment: export const IsLogged = async() => {